# How many strings will Bob need to write to prove there is no Hamiltonian cycle in a graph with n vertices?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

This was a question asked on a previous exam:

Bob is looking for a Hamiltonian cycle in a graph with $n$ vertices. His plan is to start with an arbitrary vertex, write down an adjacent vertex, and continue until either he has written $n$ distinct vertices and can return to the start vertex, or is forced to repeat a vertex. He will never write the same string of vertices, and can choose a new starting vertex each time he tries. Approximately how many strings will Bob need to write to prove there is no Hamiltonian cycle?

I know of Dirac's Theorem, but otherwise have no clue how to go about this problem.

Comment: Depends on the graph. In extreme cases, one string suffices.

Comment: Did Bob Dylan write the title to this question? :)

Comment: @Rahul, it doesn't scan very well.

Answer (score 0):

Determining whether a graph $G=(V,E)$ (undirected or directed) contains an Hamilton cycle (or even path) is [NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness) problem.
Roughly speaking, it means that in order to solve this problem you'll have to go though every possibility.

Finding an actual Hamilton cycle is not easier than determining if a graph contain one.

Regarding your question, the method you are using is called [pruning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_pruning).
Asymptotically speaking, it's worst case (or even average case) run time is ${O}(2^{n})$. 
Therefore, the answer to your question is ${O}(2^{n})$ strings in the worst case.

This problem is also known as one of the "[Millennium Prize Problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennium_Prize_Problems)
"