# Determine if the graph is Hamiltonian graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I am supposed to determine if the following graph is a Hamiltonian graph:
$G=(V,E)$ where $V=\{1,2,...,13\}$ and the set of edges is defined as follow: $E=\{(i,j)\in V\times V|11\leq i + j \leq 15\}$.

My Attempt:
I draw it and I found out, that it does not contain bridge or articulation.We learnt Dirac and Ore theorem, but none of this is applicable. So I have to find Hamiltonian circle, but I do not know how, because I think this is complicated graph for doing so.

Can  anyone help me?

Comment: A couple of points: please try to be less combative and (unintentionally?) snide. This goes into various directions. The initial version of this questions in my opinion just was not sufficiently clear. Even if one could reasonable guess that $V$ is a set of integers, one should not have to, and even once that is acompolished how is one supposed to know it is $1,...,13$ rather than $0,...,12$ or still something else. If apples in North Dakota is ideal to convey this, not really, but it's also something that is commonly done in classroom setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graph is Hamiltonian, here are two Hamilton cycles:
$(7,8,5,10,3,12,1,13,2,11,4,9,6,7)$
$(7,8,5,10,3,12,2,13,1,11,4,9,6,7)$

I constructed this cycle starting from the vertex $13$ whose neighbors are only the vertex $1,2$.

Comment: Thank you now I can see it, but is there any way, how to see it and it would not take me such a long time? Or Do I just need a lot of practice?

Comment: Are you familiar with the term NP-complete problem? or Millennium Prize Problems? I wrote a little bit about it in an aswer here,  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3469265/641481 (but just googling those terms would also be a great option, because my answer is far from being perfect.)

Comment: I am not but I will google it and read the article, thanks a lot

Comment: The short answer to your question is no, there is no "fast" way, even with a lot of practice.